# Java arithmetic int vs. long

Tags: java, math

I've done some searching on google, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. I'm trying to find out some detailed information on the way arithmetic works in Java. For example, if you add two longs together is this using the same addition operator that is used when adding two ints together? Also, what is going on under the hood when you mix longs and ints in arithmetic expressions like this:

```
long result;
long operand a = 1;
int operand b = 999999999;

result = a + b;
```

If anyone could shed some light on this or post links to relevant articles that would be awesome. Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks for the replies so far. Also, is it safe to perform arithmetic with different primitives so long as you are assigning into a variable of the widest primitive type in your expression?

Comment: This isn't a forum, it isn't really transparent to the people who have answered your question that you have a follow up. As for your edit though:
Java will not allow you to assign the result of an operation to a variable if the variable is not of a primitive type "wide" enough to hold it. Stated otherwise, you can not assign the result of "0L + 1" to an int without specifically casting to an int.

Comment: Its not completely safe as many operations can result in an underflow or an overflow. try Long.MAX_VALUE + 1  However it will always compile if you assign to the widest type.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When mixing types the int is automatically widened to a long and then the two longs are added to produce the result.  The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) explains the process for operations containing different primative types.

Specifically, these are the types each primative will widen to without requiring a cast:

- byte to short, int, long, float, or double
- short to int, long, float, or double
- char to int, long, float, or double
- int to long, float, or double
- long to float or double
- float to double

Comment: I presume this will fix the broken link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#5.6

Answer (score 7):

See: [Conversions and promotions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/conversions.doc.html)

According to that, your `int` is  promoted to `long` and then is evaluated.

Same happens with,  for instance, `int` + `double` and the rest of the primitives. ie.

```
System.out( 1 + 2.0 );// prints 3.0 a double
```

As for the addition operator <strike>I'm pretty much it is the same, but I don't have any reference of it.</strike>

A quick view to the compiler's source reveals they are different.

Namely `iadd` for int addition and `ladd` for long addition:

See this sample code:

```
$cat Addition.java 
public class Addition {
    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        int  a  = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        long b = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
        // int addition 
        int  c  = a + a;
        // long addition 
        long d = a + b;
    }
}
$javac Addition.java 
$
```

When compiled the byte code generated is this:

```
$javap -c Addition 
Compiled from "Addition.java"
public class Addition extends java.lang.Object{
public Addition();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   iconst_0
   2:   aaload
   3:   invokestatic    #2; //Method java/lang/Integer.parseInt:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
   6:   istore_1
   7:   aload_0
   8:   iconst_0
   9:   aaload
   10:  invokestatic    #3; //Method java/lang/Long.parseLong:(Ljava/lang/String;)J
   13:  lstore_2
   14:  iload_1
   15:  iload_1
   16:  iadd
   17:  istore  4
   19:  iload_1
   20:  i2l
   21:  lload_2
   22:  ladd
   23:  lstore  5
   25:  return

}
```

Look at line `16` it says: `iadd` ( for int addition ) while the  line `22` says `ladd` ( for long addition )

> *Also, is it safe to perform arithmetic with different primitives so long as you are assigning into a variable of the widest primitive type in your expression?*

Yes, and it's also *"safe"*  to perform arithmetic with smaller sizes, in the sense, they don't break the program, you just lose information.

For instance, try adding [Integer.MAX_VALUE](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to see what happens, or `int x = ( int ) ( Long.MAX_VALUE - 1 );`

Answer (score 3):

> Also, is it safe to perform arithmetic with different primitives so long as you are assigning into a variable of the widest primitive type in your expression?

It depends what you mean by safe.  It certainly won't avoid you needing to consider the possibility of overflow.

Answer (score 3):

this is called arithmetic promotion. for details look at http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/22.html

Answer (score 2):

```
int a=5;  
long b=10;  
a+=b;  
System.out.println(a);
```

The main difference is that with `a = a + b`, there is no typecasting going on, and so the compiler gets angry at you for not typecasting. 
        But with `a += b`, what it's really doing is typecasting `b` to `a` type compatible with `a`.

Comment: So it's making an invisible downcast from `long` to `int`, potentially throwing away information? Just came across this in `java.io.ByteArrayInputStream#skip(long)` and did a double-take. Never seen that before.

Answer (score 2):

This simple example could clear the doubts about data type conversion in case of arithmetic operations in java.

```
    byte a = 1;
    short b = 1;
    System.out.println(a+b);                     //Output = 2
    Object o = a+b;                              //Object becomes int
    System.out.println(o.getClass().getName());  //Output = java.lang.Integer

    int c = 1;
    System.out.println(a+b+c);                   //Output = 3
    o = a+b+c;                                   //Object becomes int
    System.out.println(o.getClass().getName());  //Output = java.lang.Integer

    long d = 1l;
    System.out.println(a+b+c+d);                 //Output = 4
    o = a+b+c+d;                                 //Object becomes long
    System.out.println(o.getClass().getName());  //Output = java.lang.Long

    float e = 1.0f;
    System.out.println(a+b+c+d+e);               //Output = 5.0
    o = a+b+c+d+e;                               //Object becomes float
    System.out.println(o.getClass().getName());  //Output = java.lang.Float

    double f = 1.0;
    System.out.println(a+b+c+d+e+f);             //Output = 6.0
    o = a+b+c+d+e+f;                             //Object becomes double
    System.out.println(o.getClass().getName());  //Output = java.lang.Double
```

---

Following is the order of data types according to range in java:

```
    byte<short<int<long<float<double
```

This is the order in which widening will happen.

Note: float has more range than long, but has smaller size.

Answer (score 0):

The answers point out to arithmetic promotion. But with that in mind I trapped into the following pitfall (shame on me) which I want to point out here:
If there are more than two operands to me it seems that calculation is performed left to right and arithmetic promotion occurs if the actual two operands in focus have a differnt type.
Thus the following code produces different results for s1 and s2. My explanation to this is:
When calculating s1 first a and b are added as two integers (and an overflow occurs) then to the result of that c (a long) is added.
When calculating s2 first c and b are added (as long) and then a is added (promoted as long) thus no overflow occurs.

```
final int a = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
final int b = 1;
final long c = 1L;
final long s1 = a + b + c;
final long s2 = c + b + a;
System.out.println("s1=" + s1 + ", s2=" + s2);
```

The output will be:
`s1=-2147483647, s2=2147483649`