# project euler #10, java, correct for small numbers

Tags: java, primes

*disclaimer, when I say "I have verified this is the correct result", please interpret this as I have checked my solution against the answer according to WolframAlpha, which I consider to be pretty darn accurate.

*goal, to find the sum of all the prime numbers less than or equal to 2,000,000 (two million)

*issue, my code will output the correct result whenever my range of tested values is approximately less than or equal to

I do not output correct result once test input becomes larger than approximately 1,300,000; my output will be off...

test input: ----199,999
test output: ---1,709,600,813
correct result: 1,709,600,813

test input: ----799,999
test output: ---24,465,663,438
correct result: 24,465,663,438

test input: ----1,249,999
test output: ---57,759,511,224
correct result: 57,759,511,224

test input: ----1,499,999
test output:--- 82,075,943,263
correct result: **82,074,443,256**

test input: ----1,999,999
test output:--- 142,915,828,925
correct result: **142,913,828,925**

test input: ----49,999,999
test output:--- 72,619,598,630,294
correct result: **72,619,548,630,277**

*my code, what's going on, why does it work for smaller inputs? I even used long, rather than int...

```
long n = 3;
long i = 2;
long prime = 0;
long sum = 0;
while (n <= 1999999) {
  while (i <= Math.sqrt(n)) {    // since a number can only be divisible by all
                            // numbers
                            // less than or equal to its square roots, we only
                            // check from i up through n's square root!
    if (n % i != 0) {       // saves computation time
      i += 2;               // if there's a remainder, increment i and check again
    } else {
      i = 3;                // i doesn't need to go back to 2, because n+=2 means we'll
                            // only ever be checking odd numbers
      n += 2;               // makes it so we only check odd numbers
    }
  }                         // if there's not a remainder before i = n (meaning all numbers from 0
                            // to n were relatively prime) then move on
  prime = n;                // set the current prime to what that number n was
  sum = sum + prime;
  i = 3;                    // re-initialize i to 3
  n += 2;                   // increment n by 2 so that we can check the next odd number

}
System.out.println(sum+2); // adding 2 because we skip it at beginning
```

help please :)

Comment: As an experiment have you tried using java's BigInteger class?

Comment: @mba12 I have not...I'm in a introductory programming class at a university, and I'm trying to only incorporate what I've learned in class, to answering the Project Euler questions...

Comment: One other thought...you are approaching and exceeding int max_value. Generally when you mix int and long together the int gets cast to a long. But there are a few situations where the long can be downcast to a int. So to be safe you might want to put a letter "L" after your integer constants. See if that helps. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073862/java-arithmetic-int-vs-long

Comment: The problem isn't with overflow. If the highest you get is numbers like 142,913,828,925, that's well within the range of `long`s, where the highest is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Comment: Hint: print the primes for a small limit, like sum of all primes less than 10...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you don't properly check whether the latest prime to be added to the sum is less than the limit. You have two nested loops, but you only check the limit on the outer loop:

```java
while (n <= 1999999) {
```

But you don't check in the inner loop:

```java
 while (i <= Math.sqrt(n)) {
```

Yet you repeatedly advance to the next candidate prime (`n += 2;`) inside that loop. This allows the candidate prime to exceed the limit, since the limit is only checked for the very first candidate prime in each iteration of the outer loop and not for any subsequent candidate primes visited by the inner loop.

To take an example, in the case with the limit value of 1,999,999, this lets in [the next prime after 1,999,999, which is 2,000,003](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=next+prime+after+1,999,999). You'll note that [the correct value, 142,913,828,922,](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+primes+less+than+or+equal+to+1999999) is exactly 2,000,003 less than your result of 142,915,828,925.

### A simpler structure

Here's one way the code could be structured, using a label and `continue` with that label to simplify structure:

```java
public static final long primeSum(final long maximum) {
    if (maximum < 2L) return 0L;
    long sum = 2L;

    // Put a label here so that we can skip to the next outer loop iteration.
    outerloop:
    for (long possPrime = 3L; possPrime <= maximum; possPrime += 2L) {
        for (long possDivisor = 3L; possDivisor*possDivisor <= possPrime; possDivisor += 2L) {
            // If we find a divisor, continue with the next outer loop iteration.
            if (possPrime % possDivisor == 0L) continue outerloop;
        }
        // This possible prime passed all tests, so it's an actual prime.
        sum += possPrime;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: +1 but can't we just compare the square of the divisor instead of using the square root? `possDivisor * possDivisor <= possPrime`

Comment: I tested that, and, surprisingly to me, it looks like it's about the same speed, so I'll change it to simplify the answer. I think another way is faster, as well, and I'll see about adding that.

Comment: the square root is calculated only once in the outer loop but it is recursive; the multiplication is called multiple times, once every interaction of the inner loop, but this is mostly terminated soon. Better approach is store found primes and only divide by these - needs only about 1/10 of the time

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex thanks, that definitely helps. the only thing I don't understand is why the code works for all input values less than about 1.3 million....

Comment: @BlueDevilSteve a comment under your question by CarlosHeuberger shows a counterexample. Your original code fails when the limit is as low as 10. Instead of 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17, it adds another 11 to give 28.